# Android Studio: Pair devices over Wi-Fi - This system does not meet requirements to support Wi-Fi pairing

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm not sure what the problem is, it says I need to update platform tools which are already updated to the latest version

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just do `File -> InvalidateCaches`

If that does not work

- In Android Studio, File -> Settings
- Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger
- Under Android Debug Bridge (adb), uncheck 'Enable adb mDNS for wireless * * debugging' and Apply
- Wait some seconds for changes to take effect
- Recheck 'adb mDNS for wireless debugging' and Apply
- On the pop-up window from Windows Defender, allow network access to adb

Comment: after router/pc reboot it works, I will try some of your options the next time it happens again and will accept your answer if any of that will work, can't confirm just now yet

Comment: works like charm thanks mate